# select from TABLE T: how does this pattern work when calculating median

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table `STATION` with a column `LAT_N`. The `LAT_N` column has an odd number of values. I'm trying to find the median for the `LAT_N` values *in this specific scenario*. This question isn't about finding the median in all possible scenarios (odd or non-odd number of values).

I'm trying to understand how/why this solution works:

```
select round(S.LAT_N, 4) from STATION as S where (select count(LAT_N) from STATION where LAT_N < S.LAT_N ) = (select count(LAT_N) from STATION where LAT_N > S.LAT_N)
```

More specifically, I'd like to know why the solution I could come up with doesn't work:

```
select round(STATION.LAT_N, 4) from STATION where (select count(LAT_N) from STATION where LAT_N < STATION.LAT_N ) = (select count(LAT_N) from STATION where LAT_N > STATION.LAT_N)
```

The first query returns one unique value (the right one), the second query returns a list of values.

It seems the key concept is with the `from STATION as S`. Why does aliasing the table make the query work?

Comment: Always alias all column references, and always , always for correlated subqueries.  It is that simple.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the concept of column reference then. Is this a column reference: `select round(S.LAT_N, 4) from STATION as S` ? Is there any difference compared to `select round(LAT_N, 4) from STATION` ? All the select happen on the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select round(STATION.LAT_N, 4) 
from STATION
where (select count(LAT_N)
       from STATION
       where LAT_N < STATION.LAT_N
      ) =
      (select count(LAT_N)
       from STATION
       where LAT_N > STATION.LAT_N
      );
```

Let me rewrite it using table aliases:

```
select round(s.LAT_N, 4) 
from STATION s
where (select count(LAT_N)
       from STATION s2
       where LAT_N < s2.LAT_N
      ) =
      (select count(LAT_N)
       from STATION s3
       where LAT_N > s3.LAT_N
      );
```

For this subquery, you think that `LAT_N` magically refers to the outer query:

```
where (select count(LAT_N)
       from STATION s2
       where LAT_N < s2.LAT_N
-------------^
      ) =
```

Or maybe I have it backwards and you think the other side refers out.  But neither do.  This query is simply:

```
where (select count(LAT_N)
       from STATION s2
       where s2.LAT_N < s2.LAT_N
-------------^
      ) =
```

And that is not very interesting.   You should qualify ALL column references in your query.  Period.  Then you wouldn't even be asking this question, because your code would have worked when you wrote it.